# Is this the best approach to restructure an array and reorganize it based off a sub array's value

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I have the below array which has a sub array of categories, I would like to output the array over and over but grouping the items into another array based on their related categories

```
    testData2: any = [{
        "id": 0,
        "name": "XyZ",
        "category": [ {
            "title": "horse"
        }, {
            "title": "food"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "something 2",
        "category": [{
            "title": "fishing"
        }, {
            "title": "horse"
        }, {
            "title": "food"
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "something 3",
        "category": [{
            "title": "horse"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "something 4",
        "category": [{
            "title": "food"
        }, {
            "title": "beer"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "something 4",
        "category": [{
            "title": "fishing"
        }]
    }
    ]
```

So far I have this which works, but i cant help wonder if there is some new JS magic which may be more perfomant to accomplish this ?

```
let newArray = [];
for (let x = 0; x < this.testData2.length; x++) {
let parent = this.testData2[x];
let child = parent.category;
for (let y = 0; y < child.length; y++) {
    let cat = child[y];
    let format = parent
    newArray.push({ group_heading: cat.title, services: [format]  })
}
}


let finalOutput = newArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
const ndx = acc.findIndex((e: any) => e.group_heading === curr.group_heading);
if(ndx > -1){
    acc[ndx].services.push(...curr.services)
} else{
    acc.push(curr)
}
return acc;
}, [])
```

which outputs this as desired

```
    [{
        "group_heading": "horse",
        "services": [{
            "id": 0,
            "name": "XyZ",
            "category": [{
                "title": "horse"
            }, {
                "title": "food"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "something 2",
            "category": [{
                "title": "fishing"
            }, {
                "title": "horse"
            }, {
                "title": "food"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "something 3",
            "category": [{
                "title": "horse"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "group_heading": "food",
        "services": [{
            "id": 0,
            "name": "XyZ",
            "category": [{
                "title": "horse"
            }, {
                "title": "food"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "something 2",
            "category": [{
                "title": "fishing"
            }, {
                "title": "horse"
            }, {
                "title": "food"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "something 4",
            "category": [{
                "title": "food"
            }, {
                "title": "beer"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "group_heading": "fishing",
        "services": [{
            "id": 2,
            "name": "something 2",
            "category": [{
                "title": "fishing"
            }, {
                "title": "horse"
            }, {
                "title": "food"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "something 4",
            "category": [{
                "title": "fishing"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "group_heading": "beer",
        "services": [{
            "id": 4,
            "name": "something 4",
            "category": [{
                "title": "food"
            }, {
                "title": "beer"
            }]
        }]
    }]
```

Comment: Questions about improving otherwise working code may be better suited for [codereview.se], but be sure to follow their [content guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure an on-topic question.

Comment: @jmoerdyk good idea. Maybe you've already done so but if not, it may also be helpful to vote to close such questions - e.g. with a reason like *Needs more focus*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do something like this:

```js
// first collect services by category
const servicesByCategory = {}
for(const service of testData2){
  for(const {title} of service.category){
    if(!servicesByCategory[title]){
      servicesByCategory[title] = []
    }
    servicesByCategory[title].push(data)
  }
}
// whip it into whatever form you need
return Object.entries(servicesByCategory)
  .map(([group_headings, services]) => ({group_headings, services}))
```